# What is the format of the ContentTypeID for Approval Forms in the xoml.wfconfig.xml files of SharePoint Designer 2010 workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I can see that the ID has 74 hex digits with the first 24 digits being the Task Content Type ID, which the first part of the Content Type ID of the form (the first 48 hex digits), but this is followed by 00 then 24 more hex digits.

What are these last 24 hex digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This identifies the copy of the content type associated with the list (it inherits from the parent content type whose id is everything before the last instance of 00.